# remainder of positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

An integer greater than 1, when divided by an integer say k, (2<=k<=11) leaves a remainder 1. find the difference of such two least integers.?

Comment: Do you know the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)?

Comment: yes i know. the remainder of f(x)/(x-a)=f(a) but how it helps?

Comment: No, that is not the one.  This deals with divisibility relations.  You might try $k=2,3$ by hand first, then $2,3,4$ and $2,3,4,5$ to see if you find a pattern.

Comment: Two least integers?  You mean $k+1$ and $2k+1$?

Answer (score 1):

if $m$ leaves remainder $1$ when divided by all the numbers in the set $\{a_1,a_2\dots a_m\}$ then that means $m-1$ is divisible by all the numbers in the set $\{a_1,a_2\dots a_m\}$. What is the minimum value for $m-1$ greater than $0$?

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting it